# Change charts title by PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet in template

Tags: php, xlsx, phpspreadsheet

I try to change chart title in .xlsx template

I open template, change cels ,write to output.

Q: How to change chart title....

```
$reader = IOFactory::createReader( 'Xlsx' );
$reader->setIncludeCharts( true );
$spreadsheet = $reader->load( storage_path( 'app/template.xlsx' ) );
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue( 'B3', 'Blabla' );

//create new from template
$writer = new Xlsx( $spreadsheet );
$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas( true );
$writer->setIncludeCharts( true );

##how to change title in all/first charts in template?
```

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I have a template with two sheets.  Sheet1 is the raw data, Sheet2 is a set of preformatted charts using data sets from Sheet1.  Each preformatted chart has a title that is bound to specific cell from Sheet1.  However when I open my template, for each chart with a title I am getting the following warning: `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx\Chart::chartTitle(): Node no longer exists`.  The new file, with charts, to be saved is all correct, except the chartTitles are all missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the method.  There are a few things to understand.

1. chartIndex - In an excel file, an id assigned to the chart based on the total number of charts starting from the first left most chart on a sheetA incrementing to the last right most chart on SheetC.  This index is the entire collection of all charts on all sheets starting with `chart1` and ending with `chartX`.  If you have ten charts `chart1,chart2,...chart10` and delete chart5, you will then have a new index of `chart1,chart2....chart9`, where the orig chart6-10 are all redindexed as `chart5-9`. In phpspreadsheet, this index appears to be represented with `$chart->getName() ;`, There is no corresponding `setName()` that would allow you to change/alter the index.
2. chartName - In an excel file, if you highlight a chart, in the upper left corner of the cells, above the `A` column, is a "chart name" drop down.  You can name your charts for organization purposes.  In excel, this field can be edited.  In phpspreadsheet, I have yet to have find what object can get/set this field.
3. chartTitle - the in chart name of a chart, IE: "Annual Revenue Projections".  In phpspreadsheet, this field is represented with `$chart->getTitle->get/setCaptionText`

So in order to find the chart you are looking to modify, you either must already know the chart index (ie: `getName()`) OR the chart visual title (ie: `getCaptionText()` ).

Because of adding deleting moving charts, I found it easier, in the excel template, to add visual titles to your charts then search for those titles/captionText in your code.  This way you don't have to have worry about tracking which chart is which index.  Use the getCaptionText to then get the getName() index.

```
  foreach ($spreadsheet->getSheetByName("SheetName")->getChartCollection() as $chart) {
    // if you know TITLE of the chart
    // TITLE is the visible title in the chart
    // Easy to know if you set the titles yourself in the template chart
    // A template chart TITLE cannot be a cell reference, will cause an error on file import
    if ($chart->getTitle()->getCaptionText() == "Chart_12") {
      $curIndex = $chart->getName() ; // = "chart3"
      $curTitle = $chart->getTitle()->getCaptionText() ;  // "Chart_12"
      $chart->getTitle()->setCaption("Quarterly Revenue Chart") ;
      break ;
    }

    // if you know the NAME (chart id) the chart
    // NAME is like the hidden chart index
    if ($chart->getName() == "chart12") {
      $chart->getTitle()->setCaption("New Chart Title") ;
      break ;
    }
  }
```